# Is there a shorter way to say “Number of times reported”?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am drawing a table. My table contains list of diagnosis along with how many times a particular diagnosis has reported in the hospital.

```
|  Diagnosis  |  Number of times reported |
|             |                           |
|             |                           |
```

Can you suggest a way to short-hand the 2nd column heading?

Comment: Quantity, or “number of reports”?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with one of the following:

- Times Reported
- No. of Reports

You could even just have "reports", since the numbers in the column will show that it means number of reports. I would suggest one of the two above though.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, as a programmer, I would just say "Reports", "Report no" (as in number), Reports count", or "Times reported", as Aric suggested.

Yes, I know this is a necromancy answer, but I suppose it might help someone else in the future.